# perl execute a command where input comes from <(cmd2 input)

Tags: bash, perl

I have a Perl script that I run in Linux 64bit and it looks like this:

```
my $ret = `/my/cmd option1 option2 <(/my/cmd2 input)`
```

This works in bash, but when I try to execute the same command as a backtick in the Perl script, it complains:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I realise that you have a solution already, but please would you run `perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{sh}'` and report what the output is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your `/bin/sh` is not linked to bash, try:

```
my $ret = `bash -c '/my/cmd option1 option2 <(/my/cmd2 input)'`
```

You can check what `/bin/sh` is linked to with:

```
% ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr  5 07:03 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: @719016 I'm happy it worked for you. You might consider using: `/my/cmd2 input | /my/cmd option1 option2` if you want to support POSIX shells.